# How to get the scalar value for both true and false positive negative values from confusion matrix of multiple classes?

Tags: python, numpy, confusion-matrix

I am trying to obtain the `TPR, TNR, PPV, NPV` from the confusion matrix. However, I keep on having errors in the float and numpy array not being a scalar value.

The confusion matrix code gives out 6 rows which represent different damage scenarios which can be found below:

```py
[[73  3  0  2  3  0]
 [11  3  0  0  0  0]
 [10  1  4  0  0  1]
 [ 4  0  2  7  2  0]
 [ 6  1  0  1  6  0]
 [ 8  0  0  2  2  2]]
```

I managed to obtain each possivite and negatives alone whcih can be found below:

```py
FP =  [20  2  1  6  4  0]
FN=  [3 6 7 6 5 6]
TP =  [32  0  0  1  1  0]
TN =  [12 59 59 54 57 61]
```

```py
# Obtaining the Confusion matrix:
conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_predicted)
print('Confusion Matrix: ', conf_matrix)

# True positives
TP = np.diag((conf_matrix))
# False positives
FP = conf_matrix.sum(axis=0) - np.diag((conf_matrix))
# False negatives
FN = conf_matrix.sum(axis=1) - np.diag((conf_matrix))
# True negatives
TN = conf_matrix.sum() - (FP + FN + TP)

# FP = FP.astype(float)
# FN = FN.astype(float)
# TP = TP.astype(float)
# TN = TN.astype(float)
FP.astype(float)
FN.astype(float)
TP.astype(float)
TN.astype(float)

print('FP = ', FP)
print('FN= ' , FN)
print('TP = ', TP)
print('TN = ', TN)
# print('FP = %4.2f%%' % FP)
# print('FN= %4.2f%%' % FN)
# print('TP = %4.2f%%' % TP)
# print('TN = %4.2f%%' % TN)

TPR = float(np.vectorize(([TP]) / (np.sum([TP] + [FN]))))
print('TPR = %4.2f%%' % (TPR * 100))
TNR = float(TN) / (TN + FP)
print('TNR = %4.2f%%' % (TNR * 100))
PPV = float(TP) / (TP + FP)
print('PPV = %4.2f%%' % (PPV * 100))
NPV = float(TN) / (TN + FN)
print('NPV = %4.2f%%' % (NPV * 100))
```

The errors that I get are those

```py
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'vectorize'
```

```py
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what line raises the error?  the `print`s?

Comment: @Yuca No, the equations: "TPR, TNR, PPV, NPV ". These variables are the cause of the errors

Comment: you need to pass a function to vectorize, you're providing the results of a function. Take a look at the documentation

Comment: @Yuca Okay, but what about the second error? I get this error because of this code: float(TP) / (TP+FN)

Comment: include the full trace of the error, what line triggers it. You should only have one error on your code, so not sure why you include 2

Comment: @Yuca here is the error:     print('TPR = %4.2f%%' % (TPR * 100))
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: @Yuca Also, If I change the first TPR code, I get the same error. "TPR = float(TP) / (TP + FN)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

Comment: @Yuca I tried to do the top answer of the question from the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053238/how-to-get-all-confusion-matrix-terminologies-tpr-fpr-tnr-fnr-for-a-multi-c?rq=1 ,however, it still gives me the error "TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"